# Retrieving user credentials from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Any ways to retrieve the password from Active Directory using C# .net? I need to integrate a 3rd party application which will have to retrieve the password based on the username from AD to pass it to a Microsoft CRM for user authentication purpose.

I couldn't find any relevant material on how to go about this. Any suggestions or links where I can find the info will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible - _retrieve the password based on the username from AD_ . Some 3rd party applications allow SSO with AD, you can ask them about that.

Comment: I second that this is not possible. The password itself would be encrypted. You might want to look into some form of pass-through authentication maybe? (ie. CRM looks at who is logged into Windows, then checks group membership of that user to see if they have access to the CRM)

Comment: @PaulMcLean: Hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks, an important distinct that I should have been more careful about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.

Windows login passwords are stored using a one-way *hash*.

Instead, you should use Active Directory / NTLM authentication to authenticate as the current domain user.